# Is it possible to find the product of two numbers given their difference?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

That is, find $a\cdot b$ given the value of $a-b$. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you will need more information.  For example, $2 - 1$ and $3 - 2$ are the same, but $2 \cdot 1 = 2$ and $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ are different.  That means that if someone tells you that $a - b = 1$, you don't know whether $a \cdot b$ is $2$ or $6$ or any number of other possibilities.

Generally, if you want to solve for $n$ unknowns, you'll want at least $n$ equations.  This is one equation in two unknowns.

Answer (score 7):

Think about this: 1 and 2 differ by 1. Their product is 2. But also, 1,000,000 and 1,000,001 differ by 1. Is their product also 2?

Answer (score 6):

You can't find the exact value of $a\cdot b$, but you can narrow it down a bit. Given $a-b=d$, we have $a\cdot b=\frac14(a+b)^2-\frac14d^2$. So if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $a\cdot b$ might be any number greater than or equal to $-\frac14d^2$.

Comment: You have a little more information, for instance $a.b$ is a square $\pmod d$.

Comment: Need $a$ and $b$ be real?

Comment: @MPW That's up to whoever is posing the question.

Comment: Agreed. I should have read your answer more carefully. +1.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is no. For example, suppose you are given that $a-b=c$ (a constant $c$). Then you would have that $ab=a(a-c)=a^2-ac=?$

Thus, you really need to be given a value for $a$ or $b$. Of course, my approach works too in a symbolic fashion, but I doubt that is what you are after here.

Answer (score 2):

$a-b$ is not sufficient to compute $ab$ as others have shown; however, if you know the value of $a+b$ also, you *can* find $ab$ to be
$$ab=\frac{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}4$$

Answer (score 1):

As induktio pointed out, you cannot find $a \cdot b$ given $a - b$ without more information.  Here is a counterexample:

Suppose I told you the difference of two numbers is 3.  Then I asked you to find their product.

Well, $5 - 2 = 3$, so maybe the product is $5 \cdot 2 = 10$.

But wait, $7 - 4 = 3$, so maybe the product is $7 \cdot 4 = 28$.

But $103 - 100 = 3$, so maybe the product $103 \cdot 100 = 10,300$.

As you can see, knowing $a - b$ is not enough to find $a \cdot b$ because there are many different numbers with different products that have the same difference (which is 3 here).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that depends on what algebraic elements you mean by "numbers". As previous posters pointed out, for what everyday-people understand as numbers, integers/real numbers that is, the problem has a negative answer.

But let $A$ be say a ring with arbitrary additive structure and a trivial multiplicative structure satisfying $a \cdot b = 0$ for all $a,b \in A$ and where $0$ is the neutral element of the underlying abelian group. In this scenario, no matter what the difference of two numbers, their product is always $0$, so you can trivially solve the given problem.